# Is gevent + gunicorn scalable and stable for production use?

Tags: python, webserver, tornado, gevent, gunicorn

I have been looking at python web servers which offer scalability and decided to go with either Tornado (used by Facebook FriendFeed) or Gevent. Since I am pretty new to this, I relied on the [Benchmark of Python Web Servers](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers) to shortlist Tornado and Gevent. Moreover, after further research I found out that:

- Gevent is not an independent web server, we need to use either libevent or gunicorn as a web server.
- libevent has its [pitfalls](http://gevent.org/servers.html), such as not supporting SSL, streaming, keep alive and websockets.
- There is no benchmarking result available which I could find which documents the performace of gevent and gunicorn used together.
- The author of gevent himself has recommended everyone to use [gevent + gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855343/run-web-app-with-gevent) for actual deployment.

My requirements:

- A highly scalable asynchronous python web server.
- SSL Support included.

I am particularly more inclined towards gevent because of its [greenlet](http://greenlet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) based approach.
I just want some hard facts to prove that gunicorn + gevent is a good choice and is highly scalable, in league with Tornado. Or is there any other python web server which meets my requirements?

Do point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 13):

As of this writing, Gunicorn is in **beta** (version 0.16) and Gevent has a **release candidate** for 1.0 ([Announcement on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gevent/hi2dKM66UHI/discussion)), so it might be reasonable to expect changes in the API (less so for Gevent) That said, as long as you track the mailing lists (here: [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/index.html#community), [gevent](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gevent)) for changes that could break your application, you should be fine with a production deployment

Gunicorn+Gevent is a good choice for an asynchronous python web server. You should perform your own tests to compare it with Tornado. Publicly available benchmarking tests might be misleading since your application may not behave as those subjected to benchmarking.

For SSL support, both [Gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html) and [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#running-tornado-in-production) recommend you run them behind a reverse proxy such as [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule). Additional advantages of running them behind a reverse proxy include improved handling of [slow clients](https://serverfault.com/questions/220046/why-is-setting-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-a-good-idea) and bad HTTP requests

Comment: Excellent answer. Just an edit though for those who might read it *today*: Gunicorn now comes with SSL support.